# grouping by Leg but also joining on the site that belongs to the earliest collection time

Tags: php, mysql

I need to do the following.
I have 9 records linked by a schedule_id.
these 9 records are broken into 3 sets of 3 for example of Leg 1 leg 2 and leg 3,
so i have the following

```
order sched leg site   date
1      1     1   1     2014-01-01
2      1     2   34    2014-12-31
3      1     1   15    2014-04-23
4      1     3   4     2014-07-12
5      1     2   89    2014-04-10
6      1     1   13    2014-09-09
7      1     3   9     2014-03-12
8      1     3   10    2014-11-10
9      1     2   11    2014-08-08
```

In my sql I group by leg so I land up with 3 records.
I need to extract the site ids that belong to the earliest and latest date in each leg group and then join my site information table to the resulting ids to extractcompanynames etc for these sites.

my sql code for the legs is as follows

```
select l.leg_no, 
                  l.start_region, 
                  r.region_name as end_region, 
                  l.rate,
                  sum(x.est_distance) as distance,
                  sum(x.est_weight) as weight,
                  count(x.order_id) as count, 
                  min(x.req_col_time) as earliesttime,
                  sum(x.total_rpb) as total_rpb, 
                  max(x.req_del_time) as latesttime from 
                  (select ord2.* from loads as l1
                  left join orders as ord2 on ord2.load_id = l1.load_id
                  left join debrief_docs as db2 on db2.oid = ord2.order_id
                  where l1.schedule_id = '.$id.'
                  union
                  select ord3.* from loads as l2
                  left join drops as drop1 on drop1.load_id = l2.load_id
                  left join orders as ord3 on ord3.drop_id = drop1.drop_id
                  left join debrief_docs as db3 on db3.oid = ord3.order_id
                  where l2.schedule_id = '.$id.')as x
                  join loads as l on l.schedule_id = '.$id.'
                  join regions as r on r.region_id = l.region_id
                  group by l.leg_no asc
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. ;)
thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's approach the important part of the question, which is getting the first and last site ids for each leg group.  I would use variables for this purpose.  The following query enumerates the leg ids:

```
  select l.*,
         (@rn := if(@l = leg_id, @rn + 1,
                    if(@l := leg_id, 1, 1)
                   )
         ) as seqnum
  from loads l cross join
       (select @rn := 0, @l := 0) vars
  order by schedule_id, leg_id, date;
```

The following summarizes the records and produces two columns, the first and last site:

```
select schedule_id, leg_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then site_id end) as first_site,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then site_id end) as last_site
from (select l.*,
             (@rn := if(@l = leg_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@l := leg_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from loads l cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @l := 0) vars
      order by schedule_id, leg_id, date
     ) l
group by schedule_id, leg_id;
```

You can then join in the rest of the tables to get the additional information that you want.

Comment: WOW. I have to admit I have no idea what you have just described. I take my hat off to you for understanding mysql at this level. Can I please ask you to break it down for me?

Comment: @TerenceBruwer . . . I thought I did.  Run the first query and notice was the seqnum column does (it enumerates the rows with the same `schedule_id` and `leg_id`).  Then run the second query and see what that does (it fetches the first and last site ids based on your logic).

Comment: Then I will thank you for your answer, and admit to my level of mysql knowledge not being up to a level where I can understand your code.